# Getting CakePHP 2.0 to Bake

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-bake

I'm having some trouble getting the Bake feature of CakePHP 2.0 working.. I think it is down to the way I've got my folder structure set-up, i.e:

[image: file structure]

htdocs is the site's root, which contains everything normally found in the 'app' folder. The htdocs/webroot/index.php file has had its CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH set as the following:

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', '..' . DS . '..' . DS . 'cakephp' . DS . 'lib');
```

I then navigate into the htdocs folder (via putty, it is hosted on a Debian 6 server), and run the following command:

```
php ../cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/cake.php bake
```

but based on the fact that the app path listed is "*/srv/www/cakeauth.tld.blue/cakephp/app/*" rather than what it should be: "*/srv/www/cakeauth.tld.blue/htdocs/*", means that it doesn't recognise htdocs as an app.

Can anyone help me set this up to run Bake in the correct place? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the Cookbook, I found that you've got the ability to pass an -app parameter when calling bake, which represents the path to the app...

So in my instance, I would run:

```
php ../cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/cake.php bake -app /srv/www/cakeauth.tld.local/htdocs/
```

Answer (score 0):

example ( 4 win ):

## env vars

D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\;D:\wamp\bin\php\includes\framework_cakephp\Cake\Console;

## php.ini

include_path = ".;D:\wamp\bin\php\includes;D:\wamp\bin\php\includes\framework_cakephp;"

## cmd:

> cake bake 
>   type path to app ( d:\wamp\www\my_app ) 
>   d: 
>   cd wamp\www\my_app\Console 
>   cake bake

Comment: I'm running a debian (Linux) server, so I don't think these will help.

Comment: difference between win and lin servers in this case is in path win:`D:\wamp\bin\php\includes` lin: `/usr/lib/php/includes`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the APP_DIR constant as well, to 'htdocs'.

It should also be defined in webroot's index.php

Comment: APP_DIR is already set to that dynamically, i.e.:

`define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));`

Comment: I'm pretty sure setting it to the hard path would let it recognise it, as well as using an absolute path for `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` instead of relative (as it directs you to in the file) would allow it to recongise the proper app normally. `These defines should only be edited if you have cake installed in a directory layout other than the way it is distributed.`